# Webpack copy-webpack-plugin Runs Too Early

Tags: webpack

I have a wepback.config.js file with the following plugin structure:

```
 /**************************************************
 Plugins imported:
    const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
    const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
    const HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin = require('html-webpack-inline-source-plugin');
    const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
    *********************************************************/

plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          inlineSource: '(main.bundle.js)',
          template: './web/leafletReact.html',
          inject: 'body'
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({

          // Eliminate comments
             comments: false,

         // Compression specific options
            compress: {
              // remove warnings
                 warnings: false,

              // Drop console statements
                 drop_console: true
            },
         }),
        new HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin(),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                {
                    from: path.join(__dirname, '/build/*.html'),
                    to: path.join(__dirname, '/assets/dist'),
                    toType: 'dir',
                    flatten: true
                }
            ])
    ]
```

Even though CopyWebpackPlugin is listed last, it runs prior to the completion of HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin .  Is there a way to force CopyWebpackPlugin  to wait until all the other plugins are finished?

Comment: I can't help with this but, what i can say is listing CopyWebpackPlugin last wont make it run at the end because of the way that the webpack plugin system works.

Comment: i have a similar issue. Do you find any workaround?

Comment: @Anand I never found and restructured my project so that I didn't need to copy things.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone having this issue please use [FileManagerWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/gregnb/filemanager-webpack-plugin). Since `copy-webpack-plugin` is not designed to wait for the build to complete hence the error. Hope this helps anybody having the same problems. Cheers, sigfried.